# Selenium commands are not working through Jmeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I am trying to execute selenium commands through jmeter. I am getting the following error: 
**

```
ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (7a2e8c66b4fbd3c2a78cc3ea8c9cb449) because of the following error:
NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (7a2e8c66b4fbd3c2a78cc3ea8c9cb449)' contains unresolvable namespaces.
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.106)*
```

*

Steps I have done:

1. Install Jmeter, download libraries, Install ChromeWebDriver
2. Assigned the path of chromewebriver to Path in jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config Element
3. Imported necessary libraries in web Driver sampler

Attaching a screenshot of my WebDriver sampler:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlRd1.png)

Can anyone help please?

Comment: looks like you are using "pkg" as if it were a driver instance.

Answer (score 0):

C'mon, you're trying to locate the element using `ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (7a2e8c66b4fbd3c2a78cc3ea8c9cb449)` line which is not a valid [XPath expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) to me so most probably you want to use something else, not `${Browser}` as the XPath query.

First of all try hard-coding the necessary XPath expression into your script like:

```
var browser_button=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//button[text()='Some text')]'))
```

and once it will be successful you can substitute it with a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) of your choice.

A couple more hints:

1. Don't refer JMeter Variables as `${Browser}`, use **WDS.vars** shorthand instead like:

   ```
   var myVar = WDS.vars.get('myVar')
   ```
2. Don't use Thread.sleep(), it's a performance antipattern, consider using [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) instead

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)

Comment: Hi... I was able to resolve the issue. No problem with jmeter or selenium integration. The element was present in I frame.